# Como colocar un elemento a la par de otro en boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

estoy probando boostrap y queria poner unas cards, use el snippet que hay en la documentacion de Boostrap pero a la hora de poner dos tarjetas (las cuales tienen el tamaño para estar una a la par de la otra) la siguiente se pone abajo y no a la par. aqui les dejo el codigo de la tarjeta:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 380px;">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

intente ponerlo en un div con la clase container ya que vi un ejemplo en la documentacion donde salian 3 divs en horizontal pero al aplicarlo en mi caso siguen apareciendo uno debajo del otro. como podria hacer para ponerlos uno a la par del otro? muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar filas (row) y columnas (col) de bootstrap para eso, de este modo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 380px;">
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 380px;">
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En este enlace a [su documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) aprenderás más sobre el grid de bootstrap.